# C++ Return Pointer of Type T from Char Array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers, typedef

We are working on a project that requires us to make and manage a heap in C++. We are using a character array to store our memory (no use of "new" in the project). We have an allocate function that needs to return a pointer of type T. We have a couple of type defs and a template to help us out

```
template <typename T>
typedef T    value_type;
typedef value_type*  pointer;
```

So we need to return a "pointer". The question:

**How can we return a "pointer" that points to a certain index in our character array?**

Say if the start of the allocated block points at address 5, and the typename T is int. How can we make an int pointer (using our "pointer") that points to the array index at 5?

We have tried using `reinterpret_cast <pointer> (a[index])` to cast the array index to a pointer. Additionally we have tried `reinterpret_cast <pointer> (a + index)` to get the array pointer, move it up by index, and cast that to our type pointer. Each time, the pointer points to something like "0xfffffffffff" or a bunch of f's followed maybe by a 0c or some random value, thus leading to a segmentation fault once we dereference it later in the program (in the construct function for example).

Thanks!

edit the array "a" is our character array

Comment: What is the declared type of `a`? If it's `T a[]`, then can you just do `a+index` or `&a[index]`? I don't see a need for the cast.

Comment: sorry, should have made that clearer. The array "a" is our character array mentioned.

Comment: An issue with byte alignment?  You probably have to account for the fact that elements in your heap have to be aligned on the proper boundary: long on 4 byte, long long on 8, etc

Comment: Does it work when `T` is `char`? (If not, there must be a deeper issue, unrelated to the change of data type.)

Comment: Well, trying not to get into too many specifics but whenever we allocate memory, we create sentinels on either end of a block ,indicating the size of the block. The size of the block is the number of blocks multiplied by the size of the type of data (for example allocate(5) for type int - type is given in template - will allocate 20 indexes in the array, say indexes from 20 to 40). At the end of the allocation, we have & need to return a pointer to the index at the start of the block. I'm not 100% sure how alignment would fall into this since we are dealing with essentially a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

I think we figured it out. We had:

`reinterpret_cast <pointer> (a[index])`

Which would give us the pointer of the index of the array (basically a pointer **of** a value, not a pointer **to** a value).

We changed it to

`reinterpret_cast <pointer> (&a[index])`

Which would give us a pointer to the index of the array (basically a pointer **to** the value, not **of** the value). Sorry if this subtle use of "of" and "to" doesn't make since. I suppose it's the difference between

`int a = 5`

`int* k = &a`

vs

`int* k = a //even though this wouldnt compile`